# java inline class declaration and allocation

Tags: java

What is the syntax to declare a class and allocate it inline in one go?

EDIT: I've updated my question -- I need to customize the behavior of implemented method by passing some vars to the constructor.

ie

```
Foo foo = new Foo(int a) implements Bar {
     int a;

     public Foo() {
        this.a = a;
     }

     // Bar's method
     void xyz() {
         if (this.a == ... ) ...
     }
};
```

Comment: @SivaKumar If you recommend to read some books, please also describe witch ones you recommend that cover the topics of annonymous classes and inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** do what you need to do. You just can't do it the way you think it should be done. (Classic XY problem.)

You **can** access a value in your overridden method in `Bar`, you just can't use an instance variable initialized by a constructor to do it.

Just do it like this:

```
final int aInFoo = a;
Bar foo = new Bar {
    // Bar's method
    void xyz() {
        if (aInFoo == ... ) ...
    }
};
```

Or, if your value of `a` can change inside `Foo`, try it like this:

```
final int aInFoo = a;
Bar foo = Bar {
    int a1 = aInFoo;

    // Bar's method
    void xyz() {
        if (this.a1 == ... ) ...
    }
};
```

But if you're getting that complex, you'd be better off using a named class, perhaps a named inner class, rather than an anonymous one. How to do that?

```
Foo foo = new Foo(a);

// later in the same file...
class Foo implements Bar {
    int a;
    Foo(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    // Bar's method
    void xyz() {
        if (this.a == ... ) ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I should have included examples of those.

Answer (score 6):

What you're describing is an *[anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)*, and so you can't use the name when declaring the variable, because officially it doesn't have a name. (Under the covers, as an implementation detail, it does.)

To declare the variable, typically one uses the interface or base class one is implementing/subclassing as the type, e.g.:

```
Bar foo = new Bar() {
    @Override
    void someRelevantMethod() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Re your comment:

> i need to pass params to Bar, hence I need constructor in Fo

Then you need to use an *[inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)* rather than an anonymous one, because anonymous classes [can't have an explicit constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1).

But you may *not* need a constructor, because:

- Anonymous classes have access to the instance fields of their enclosing instance.
- Anonymous classes close over the `final` variables in scope where you create them.

So for instance, if the variables you're using to modify the behavior of the base class *don't change*, just declare them `final` in the enclosing scope, give them their values, and use those values in the implementation. Or if they change, but they're instance fields in the enclosing class, just use them directly.

But if the values change and aren't available from instance fields of the enclosing class, you'll want an inner class (or even possibly a [static nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), or standalone class) instead.

Comment: Aren't we encouraging bad questions by answering them?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi: I agree with the general sentiment, absolutely. Don't think this is an example, but maybe it's a close call. If you don't know the term, it's kinda hard to look up. Basic questions aren't necessarily *bad* questions, remember.

Comment: i need to pass params to Bar, hence I need constructor in Foo. ie. I need to manipulate instance vars in the implemented method of Bar.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi if you feel its question is badly written, you can always edit it so he can learn, instead of just downvote it and/or ignore it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I hear u, but isn't obvious that the OP hasn't done any effort and not will to do any?

Comment: @zx6r: I've updated the answer. You can't use an anonymous class if you really need to define a constructor. But you may not need to.